# Balancing biscoff spread for stuffed brownies

Tags: baking, substitutions, dessert, brownies

There is a recipe online for nutella stuffed brownies that I really like, and I want to swap out the nutella for biscoff to make a biscoff stuffed brownie. The recipe is this one in question: https://www.recipetineats.com/outrageous-nutella-brownies/

The biscoff spread is this one: (https://www.lotusbiscoff.com/en-gb/producten/lotus-biscoff-spread)

The problem is not with the recipe, but with the substitution. I think that just freezing a slab of biscoff (like it says to do with nutella) would make for a cloying brownie.

Is there anything I can do to "mellow" the biscoff spread so it isn't too cloying? I am thinking of blending in a neutral oil/butter to add more bulk without any flavour. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options come to mind for me:

The first option I would suggest is simply using a thinner layer of biscoff spread. You can use one that is just a couple of millimetres thick instead of the half a centimetre of nutella in the recipe.

The second option would be to look up a recipe for biscoff cookie dough (American-style edible cookie dough flavoured with biscoff) and use that as filling for a more mellow flavour.

Comment: Ah! I hadn't even thought of a thinner layer. It would be difficult to spread it out into a single layer, but I think if I melt the biscoff in the pan in the oven, then let cool, then freeze it should work. It might also mess with the cooking times (since there will be less frozen filling to come up to temp), but I think I'll try it! Thanks!

Comment: @impo I presume you're freezing it on some greaseproof paper or similar; just put another piece of paper on top and press it thinner or roll it out. I don't know if I would expect it to handle being heated well although I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: @dbmag9 I had not thought of that! A good idea, I will try it, thank you!

Comment: @impo I hope it goes well!